# ActionHandler server handler scope

Tags: gwt, scope

We recently switch to GWT in my company and I have a question. How to configure the ActionHandler server handler scope ?

In our current design, we use `configureHandlers` method and it creates singleton handler. We consider that as a bad design and would a per-request handler. Is it possible ?

Here our `ServerModule` that creates the handlers:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DefaultModule.class)
public class ServerModule extends HandlerModule
{
    private Map<Class, Object> _handlersMap;

    @Resource(name = "handlersConfigurationMap")
    // Working around a Spring bug https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7916
    public void setHandlersMap(final Map<Class, Object> handlersMap)
    {
        _handlersMap = handlersMap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureHandlers()
    {
        for (Class handlerClassName : _handlersMap.keySet())
        {
            //noinspection RedundantCast,unchecked
            bindHandler((Class<? extends Action>)handlerClassName, (Class)_handlersMap.get(handlerClassName).getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're using the [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) library or not. Assuming you are then quite a while ago I had similar thoughts and created a patch that can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/issues/detail?id=22&can=1). Unfortunately its Guice based and not Spring but the ideas are probably still applicable. I have to say though that after doing this I never used it and found that for my applications singleton scope was fine.

Comment: we use gwt-dispatch. I am very new to gwt so I didn't know it exists others ways.